# Proof of $\lim_{x\to 4}x^2 = 16$ using the definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Hi I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzsWhDlTcqY), and at 11:32, the professor concluded that $9|x-4| < ε$. The way I see it: $|x+4| < 9 ⟺ |x-4||x+4| < 9|x-4| \;∀ x ≠ 4\;$ **(1)**. We also have $|x-4||x+4| < ε \;$ **(2)**. From **(1)** and **(2)**, it doesn't seem enough to conclude that $9|x-4| < ε$. Am I missing something?

I was able to come up with a proof, but it doesn't look very neat, I wonder if there may be a better way, but here is mine:

Set δ = $\sqrt {ε +16} - 4\qquad (ε > 0) $

When $0 < |x-4| < δ$,

we have: $0 < |x-4| < \sqrt {ε +16} - 4$

$⟺ -(\sqrt {ε +16} -4) < x - 4 < \sqrt {ε +16} -4\qquad (x ≠ 4)$

$⟺ 8 - \sqrt {ε +16} < x < \sqrt {ε +16}\qquad(x ≠ 4)$

$⟺ - \sqrt {ε +16} < 8 - \sqrt {ε +16} < x < \sqrt {ε +16}\qquad(x ≠ 4)$

$⟹ |x| < \sqrt {ε +16}\qquad(x ≠ 4)$

$⟺ -16 ≤ x^2 -16 < ε\qquad(x ≠ 4)$ **(1)**

------(Now I'm going to prove $- ε < x^2 - 16$)------

• When $0 < ε ≤ 48,\quad 0 ≤ 8 - \sqrt {ε +16} < x$

$⟺ (8 - \sqrt {ε +16})^2 - 16 < x^2 - 16$ **(2)**

Consider $f(ε) = [(8 - \sqrt {ε +16})^2 - 16] -(-ε)$

$f(ε) = 2(\sqrt {ε +16} - 4)^2 > 0 $

$⟹ -ε < (8 - \sqrt {ε +16})^2 - 16$ **(3)**

**(2),(3)** $⟹ -ε < x^2 - 16$ **(4)**

**(1),(4)** $⟹ -ε < x^2 - 16 < ε ⟺ |x^2 - 16| < ε$ **(i)**

• When $ε > 48,\quad -ε<-16 ≤ x^2 -16 < ε ⟺ |x^2 - 16| < ε$ **(ii)**

**(i),(ii)** $⟹ |x^2 - 16| < ε \quad ∀ x\;:\;  0 < |x-4| < δ,\;(δ = \sqrt {ε +16} - 4)$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to 4}x^2 = 16$

Please let me know if there is a better way. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: You can take  $\delta>0$ such that $|x+4|=x+4<5$ and have $|x^2-16|<5\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-4||x+4|\leq |x-4|(|x-4|+8)<|x-4|(1+8)$ if $|x-4|<1$. So $|x-4||x+4|<\epsilon$ if $|x-4|<\frac {\epsilon } 9$ and $|x-4|<1$. Take $\delta =\min \{1, \frac {\epsilon } 9\}$.

Comment: I do not understand downvoting your answer. It's better (as you did) to start with $\delta$, simplify things and at the very end decide how small $\delta$  should be.  The studied limit is quite simple, but the strategy pays off at more complicated limits (+).

Answer (score 1):

The video proof explicitly states that if $\delta < 1$, then $|x+4|<9$.

But remember, that is only the "scratch" part of the video. It is the part where we are looking for what we should set $\delta$ to. Once we decide on a delta, we need to also prove that it is correct.

---

As for your proof, it looks ok but it is quite messy. I think the video proof is much nicer. Remember, the **proof** part of the video is very short (once you come up with the delta), the main part is just looking for $\delta$.

The proof is quite simple:

1. Let $\epsilon > 0$.
2. Let $\delta = \min\{1, \frac\epsilon9\}$.
3. Let $x$ be any value such that $0<|x-4|<\delta$.
4. From (3) we can conclude that $|x+4|<9$.
5. Then (I am writing the reasoning behind each (in)equality alongside it):
   $$\begin{align}|f(x)-16| &= |x^2-16| \\
   &= |x-4||x+4|&\text{algebraic manipulation}\\
   &\leq 9|x-4|&\text{from (4)}\\
   &\leq 9 \delta&\text{from (3)}\\
   &\leq 9\frac\epsilon9&\text{from (2)}\\
   &=\epsilon\end{align}$$
6. Thus, $|f(x)-16|<\epsilon$, which is what we wanted to show.